# Not able to run Custome Angular Project in Asp.net core Angular project

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, migration, single-page-application

I am migrating from asp.net frame work to dotnet 5, I have deleted the ClientApp angular project that came by default and add custom angular folder into the project. Now I am not able to change the  in csproj file as If I do that the solution is not loading that project.

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
<IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
<SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>

--solution
--->project
---->Apps
----->AngularProject
```

I have added AngularProject under Apps folder.

Is there any workaround so that I can add and run custom angular project.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a folder ClientApp in the project and change the spa.options.sourcepath to the custom created angular project.

Comment: So were you able to answer your own question?  If so, please mark your post as answered.